# R: profiling issue: what is tryCmpfun?

Tags: r

I am profiling a function that takes 150 units of time. But according to the profiling tool, the actual body of the function takes 30 units of time. What is the other 120 units of time spent on?

The profiler tool basically says
[image]

What's it doing?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test to see what's going on.

Comment: Can you please share which `library` and profiling function you are using.